# Why are square brackets preventing shell expansion?

Tags: shell, quoting, filenames, wildcards

'4800483343' is a directory, and 'file1' & 'file2' are two files in it.

Why is the following happening?

```
$ ls 4800483343
file1 file2

$ md5sum 4800483343/*
36468e77d55ee160477dc9772a99be4b  4800483343/file1
29b098f7d374d080eb006140fb01bbfe  4800483343/file2

$ mv 4800483343 4800[48]3343

$ md5sum 4800[48]3343/*
md5sum: 4800[48]3343/*: No such file or directory

$ md5sum '4800[48]3343'/*
36468e77d55ee160477dc9772a99be4b  4800[48]3343/file1
29b098f7d374d080eb006140fb01bbfe  4800[48]3343/file2
```

What other characters cause this?

Comment: The command `mv dir d[i]r` should result in the error "mv: cannot move ‘dir’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘dir/dir’".  Did you by chance run instead `mv dir 'd[i]r'` ?

Comment: I changed the directory name to make it simpler. The actual directory name is '4800483343'. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I added a revised answer for the new question.   The key difference between the two versions is that the glob `d[i]r` happened to match the name of an existing directory while the glob `4800[48]3343` did not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Answer for original question

> Why are square brackets preventing shell expansion

*Square brackets do not prevent shell expansion but quotes do.*

I suspect that the commands that you actually ran were as follows

This runs md5sum on the files in `dir/`:

```
$ md5sum d[i]r/*
02fdd7309cef4d392383569bffabf24c  dir/file1
db69ce7c59b11f752c33d70813ab5df6  dir/file2
```

This moves `dir` to `d[i]r` with the quotes preventing the expansion of the square brackets:

```
$ mv dir 'd[i]r'
```

This looks for directory `dir` which no longer exists:

```
$ md5sum d[i]r/*
d[i]r/*: No such file or directory
```

Because of the quotes, the following looks in the new directory named `d[i]r`:

```
$ md5sum 'd[i]r'/*
02fdd7309cef4d392383569bffabf24c  d[i]r/file1
db69ce7c59b11f752c33d70813ab5df6  d[i]r/file2
```

#### Answer for revised question

In the revised question, the directory 4800483343 exists and the following command run:

```
mv 4800483343 4800[48]3343
```

What happens when this command is run depends on whether the glob `4800[48]3343` matches any existing directory.  If no directory matches that, then `4800[48]3343` expands to itself `4800[48]3343` and the directory `4800483343` is moved to the directory `4800[48]3343`.

Consequently:

1. The command `md5sum 4800[48]3343/*`  will return the error "No such file or directory" because no directory exists which matches the glob `4800[48]3343`.
2. The command `md5sum '4800[48]3343'/*` will correctly find the files because the quotes prevent expansion of the glob.

#### Examples of globs

Let's create two files:

```
$ touch a1b a2b
```

Now, observe these globs:

```
$ echo a[123]b
a1b a2b
$ echo a?b
a1b a2b
$ echo *b
a1b a2b
```

Comment: That makes sense. So square brackets always have to be escaped when using a `*` in an argument? Are there any other characters that similarly have to be escaped?

Comment: `*`, `?`,  and `[]` are all glob characters.  If they are unquoted, they are active,  If they are quoted, they are not active.

Answer (score 3):

A bracket expression represents any number of *single* characters that might match a *single* character position. This simple rule of thumb tends to get fuzzy when you start dealing with multi-byte characters and `[[.`collating elements`.]]` and/or `[[=`equivalence`=]]` classes, but there are many programs that don't fully support multi-char matches for those as yet anyway. And ASCII digits 0-9 are pretty sure bets to always match themselves and collate in order in a bracket expression for basically any locale. POSIX, at least, requires that this last bit is true.

For example:

```
cd /tmp
for d in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do mkdir "$d"; done
ls [0123]
```

---

```
0:

1:  

2:

3:
```

Basically a single `[` bracket expression `]` shell glob is simply a more specific `?` any char glob.

```
echo ?/; echo [2468]/
```

---

```
0/ 1/ 2/ 3/ 4/ 5/ 6/ 7/ 8/ 9/
2/ 4/ 6/ 8/
```

And so the shell glob `4800[48]3343` will match either of the following two current directory filenames:

```
480043343
480083343
```

...but it will not match...

```
4800483343
4800843343
4800[48]3343
```

If you want to use the literal square brackets in your filenames, you can match those in bracket expressions:

```
touch 4800\[48]3343
echo 4800[[]48[]]3343
```

---

```
4800[48]3343
```

The shell's square bracket globs don't take much quoting, either. There are three characters that the shell will recognize in a list context as beginning a glob expression:

```
* ? [
```

The right square bracket without the leading left square bracket is just another character and needs no quoting:

```
echo ]
```

---

```
]
```

So if you just quote the left square bracket for any pair they will always be literally interpreted. Else you can disable globbing entirely anytime you like with:

```
set -f
```

Turn it back on at your leisure with:

```
set +f
```

Answer (score 2):

If you did rename the directory `4800483343` to `4800[48]3343`, then you need to escape the metacaracters `[ ]` with some form of quoting. All this will work:

```sh
$ ls 4800\[48\]3343/*
$ ls "4800[48]3343"/*
$ ls '4800[48]3343'/*
```

All will correctly print:

```sh
4800[48]3343/file1  4800[48]3343/file2
```

However, if you leave the metacharacters `[` and `]` unquoted, they will be interpreted as a bracket description for «Pathname Expansion». Search the bash manual for «Pathname expansion» and you will find this:

> ```
>  [...]     Matches any one of the enclosed characters.
> ```

And some more text explaining how this is suposed to work. In short:

```sh
A [abc] will match ONE character, either an `a`, an `b` or an `c`.
```

Therefore, unquoted `4800[48]3343` will match `480043343` or `480083343`.
None of which are the directory: `4800[48]3343`, and no expansion will be done by: `ls 4800[48]3343/*` as no directory is found. A more complex expansion will match the directory, and the expansion will work:

```sh
$ ls 4800$'\133'[48][48]$'\135'3343/*
```

But probably here I am getting too deep into this issue :-)